# Can't validate Login on VB

Tags: vb.net, error-handling, database-connection

I keep getting this error: system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand and can't connect to my in order to validate my login

```
Imports System.Data.SqlClient


Public Class Login
    Dim strSql As String = "Data Source=FILIPA-PC\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=NIC;Integrated Security=True;"
    Dim connection As SqlConnection
    Dim SQL As SqlCommand
    Dim str As String
    Dim perfil As String

    Public Sub BtnLogin_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BtnLogin.Click
        Dim username, password As String
        username = UsernameTextBox.Text
        password = PasswordTextBox.Text
        str = "SELECT Tipo_Perfil FROM Perfil INNER JOIN Login ON Perfil.ID_Perfil =Login.ID_Utilizador INNER JOIN Utilizador ON Utilizador.ID_Utilizador=Login.ID_Utilizador WHERE username =  '" + username + "' AND passeword = '" + password + "'"
        connection = New SqlConnection(strSql)
        connection.Open()
        SQL = New SqlCommand(str, connection)
        perfil = ""
        'perfil = SQL.ExecuteScalar.ToString
        perfil = Convert.ToString(SQL)
        MessageBox.Show(perfil)
        connection.Close()
        Select Case (perfil)
            Case "Administrador"
                Administrador.Show()
            Case "Utilizador"
                Utilizador.Show()
        End Select


    End Sub


End Class
```

I don't know what the problem is, can't connect to my database to validate the login, and btw the fields are all correct. No errors there

Comment: `System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand` is not an error. You should find and post the actual error message

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of possibilities, but without seeing the error message you're getting, it's hard to know.:

1. Is your database server case-sensitive?
2. If so, are you using the correct casing in your connection string?
3. You're using "Integrated Security" in your connection string.  Are you running the
   application as a user who's been given access to the server and the
   database?